# Convert M4a to Mp3

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to convert in my App M4a file to Mp3 file, i try to use the TSlibraryimport but it not doing this proccess .

it can be done also by moving the m4a file to nsdata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use CoreAudio

and LAME codec (this isn't included in iOS for license reasons)

some example of converting audio types via CoreAudio:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ConvertFile/Introduction/Intro.html

and CoreAudio docs:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html

and supported filetypes for CoreAudio:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/SupportedAudioConverterFormats/SupportedAudioConverterFormats.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003577-CH7-SW1

Comment: @MTA Did you end up finding a simple solution to this?  I am looking through these links and I have no idea where to start on this.

Comment: Hai Did you find the Solution from this link?

Comment: No i am not find any solution from above link.is anyone?